# Cycle counter: on which ARM will the code successfully run?

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, arm

On a Raspberry Pi 3b, which is ARM Cortex-A5 processor, ARMv7 architecture, I am reading the cycle counter registers from the PMU (Performance Monitor Unit):

```
uint32_t cycle_counter_read (void)
{
  uint32_t cc = 0;
  __asm__ volatile ("mrc p15, 0, %0, c9, c13, 0":"=r" (cc));
  return cc;
}
```

I'd like to understand on which ARM processors will this code run successfully, other than the one in Raspberry Pi 3B. Which ARM info is important for this:

- processor name (Cortex A5 only?)
- architecture (ARMv7 only?)
- AArch32 and/or AArch64?
- the combination of the above?
- something else?

[List of ARM architectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ARM_microarchitectures).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to understand on which ARM processors will this code run successfully, other than the one in Raspberry Pi 3B. Which ARM info is important for this

Well, `mrc p15` is moving into a register from coprocessor 15.

So, the important info is just whether the processor has a PMU on coprocessor #15.

I think the feature is optional (although strongly recommended), so it's always possible you'll come across a custom ARM chip that doesn't have a PMU. Hopefully it's always on coprocessor #15 at least, when it *is* present.

Probably the best you can do is find a list of chips known to have one. You can use the `ID_AA64DFR0_EL1, AArch64 Debug Feature Register 0` on ARM v8, but I don't know of a reliable mechanism before that.

Searching for "arm pmu" found, for example [this list](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/arm/pmu.txt) in the Linux kernel documentation:

```
ARM cores often have a PMU for counting cpu and cache events like cache misses
and hits. 

...

- compatible : should be one of
    "apm,potenza-pmu"
    "arm,armv8-pmuv3"
    "arm,cortex-a73-pmu"
    "arm,cortex-a72-pmu"
    "arm,cortex-a57-pmu"
    "arm,cortex-a53-pmu"
    "arm,cortex-a35-pmu"
    "arm,cortex-a17-pmu"
    "arm,cortex-a15-pmu"
    "arm,cortex-a12-pmu"
    "arm,cortex-a9-pmu"
    "arm,cortex-a8-pmu"
    "arm,cortex-a7-pmu"
    "arm,cortex-a5-pmu"
    "arm,arm11mpcore-pmu"
    "arm,arm1176-pmu"
    "arm,arm1136-pmu"
    "brcm,vulcan-pmu"
    "cavium,thunder-pmu"
    "qcom,scorpion-pmu"
    "qcom,scorpion-mp-pmu"
    "qcom,krait-pmu"
```